# Como exibir PDF em pop-up ao clicar em link utilizando apenas html/css?

Tags: html, css

Em determinada página de um site, tenho uma imagem com um link apontando para um arquivo PDF. Da forma que está atualmente, quando o usuário clica na imagem, o arquivo PDF é aberto em outra aba do navegador.

Porém preciso encontrar uma forma de, quando o usuário clicar na imagem, o PDF ser exibido em uma `pop-up` na página atual, de preferência utilizando apenas `html/css`.
O código atualmente está assim:

```
<a href="images/CartaServicos/Assinatura-Externa.pdf" target="_blank"> 
    <img src="images/CartaServicos/AssinaturaExterna.PNG" alt="AssinaturaExterna"/>
</a>
```

Se puderem dar uma luz, agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Leandro, acredito que a única solução seja com Javascript.
O link será aberto em uma nova janela, e com o Javascript você pode definir o tamanho dessa nova janela, gerando assim um "pop-up".

```
<a href="http://seulinkaqui.com" 
  target="popup" 
  onclick="window.open('http://seulinkaqui.com','popup','width=600,height=600'); return false;">
```